# deleteObject method of aws sdk for javascript was success but display 403 error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

The function triggered with onclick event is below:

```
async function deleteImage(image) {
    var bucketRegion = "ap-northeast-1";
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: {accessKeyId},
        secretAccessKey: {secretAccessKey},
        region: bucketRegion,
    });
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: "ap-northeast-1" });
    var params = {
        Bucket: {Bucket},
        Key: image,
    };

    return s3.deleteObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("err: ", err, err.stack);
        else console.log("data: ", data); 
        }).promise();
}
```

This function work but the error message described below was displayed on console.

> SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.

Why the function was success but 403 error was occured?

Comment: How are you determining that the function was successful? As a general rule it's better to not mix callbacks and promises in the same function call.

Comment: thank you for comment.
I determined successful by confirmed object deleted from s3 bucket.

Comment: solved this problem by removing callback function.
thank you!

Comment: One question: why do you have `Bucket: {Bucket}`? If there's a global variable named `Bucket`, you should be able to simply use `const params = { Bucket, Key: image }`